# Website elements moved around and look different on different computers?

Tags: html, css

I recently made my website live, http://goroam.org just to see how it would look live, on my laptop everything looks fine and great nothing is out of place. However on other friends laptop's there are some issues with pictures being to far or to close to each other and other small issues, however every friend's laptop that has a issue, not one of them are the same. Any ideas to what is happening?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Well, try resizing your browser's window and you'll see, why the differences appear. First, change your `content` div's width to `100%` instead of that fixed value and erase the `margin` setting. Next, change this line: `<div style="position: relative; z-index:9999;top:-55px; left:-210px;">` to this line: `<div style="position: relative; z-index:9999;top:-55px;">`. After that, the buttons position themselves according to browser window's size. This resolves only one of your problems, but I hope this gives you some idea where to start.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I'm answering your question right, but different computers (with different operating systems and browsers) see almost every website a tiny bit differently. make 100% sure that you are not using any absolute positioning, and you are not depending your elements and their position and sizes based browser versions/type or anything similar to that. I don't know how you made your website, but try using % positioning, and make sure that your browser is not zoomed in when testing :D Please provide more information (codes and scripts) for a better answer.

P.S I am getting the same issue, I guess you are the only one that sees the website normaly, I really suggest you checking your browser and settings!